# Best frequency for underwater transmission

Tags: acoustics, water, frequency

What is the best frequency for a high data rate of underwater transmission? I have read that the threshold of hearing underwater is around 170 to 180 db. Can this be useful in calculating the best frequency for transmission What source could be used to generate that frequency?

Comment: Over what range would you like to transmit sound ? In what region of the ocean? Or is it in a large lake? Underwater acoustics is complicated, you need to consider water depth, bottom material, temperature and sound speed profile, etc. Your best bet is probably to read some papers on the topic.

Comment: i'm under the impression that volumes over 120 db can cause hearing damage, hearing and data rate seem to conflict, could you clear this up?

Comment: I am more concerned with transmission of data. At present, we will be testing in a fresh water lake.

Comment: Are you talking about transmission using compression waves, or electromagnetic waves?

Comment: As I mention in the following answer, https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/266046/59023, there are three critical things that matter: the acoustic impedance, hearing threshold, and hearing frequency response function (i.e., it's not flat).  Much like in Earth's atmosphere, the "best" frequency must be tailored for the environment and the intended receiver.