# Doppler effect with and without varying intensity of sound?

Tags: waves, doppler-effect

Take the classical example of fast moving Car whizzing past you.
You hear the .....oooooooOOooooooo.....
sound.

But in that case most of the effect we are observing is the change in intensity of sound. The sound gets louder as car approaches and then fades away as car goes away.

A video showed that a 50mph speeding car, produces doppler effect of shifting frequency from 500Hz fo 530Hz.

Is this change in frequency what we hear mostly, or is it the changing loudness of sound that we mostly hear?

In other words, does the highly changing loudness cover the doppler effect of changing frequency?

Or, is the doppler effect distinctly detectable by our ears, despite the changing loudness effect?

Finally, is it possible to somehow observe the doppler effect experimentally (by human ears) without the changing intensity?
How different (or better) will the effect feel(or sound) then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doppler shift and change in intensity of a sound wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/266205/doppler-shift-and-change-in-intensity-of-a-sound-wave) and there is also the difference between the intensity of a sound wave and the [loudness of the sound wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudness).

Comment: You are correct. Both frequency and amplitude change as the car goes by,  but the Doppler effect only describes the frequency change. The amplitude change is real, but Doppler doesn't pay it any attention.

Comment: I don't see how my question is duplicate of the other question mentioned. Maybe, what Iam asking is not very clearly explained by me. (Even though I have put it 4 different ways).

Answer (score 1):

The Doppler effect (i.e. the shift in frequency of the received sound) manifests itself as the change in the pitch of the sound, and is often easily noticeable to the human ear as it occurs in traffic, with or without the accompanying change in loudness. This is similar to distinguishing two different notes played on the same musical instrument, with different loudness. It is especially easy to do with the sirens of emergency vehicles which are loud enough to be heard for a long time as they approach and recede from you, and have distinct pitches you could "hum to". This might be harder to do with the engine noise of a typical car, but often still possible.

If a fire truck blaring its siren drives past you at a modest speed of 80 km/h = 22 m/s, using a speed of sound of 343 m/s, the ratio between the pitches heard as the truck is approaching and receding is
$$\frac{f_a}{f_r}=\frac{343+22}{343-22}=1.138.$$
To put this in familiar terms, two semitones, which is the pitch increment between two of the closest black keys on a piano, or the pitch increment when moving two frets up on a guitar string, corresponds to a frequency ratio is $2^{2/12}=1.123$. This is less than the Doppler shift of the fire truck siren (or anything else passing by you at the same speed).

Comment: Your equation corresponds to the case where both truck and me are moving towards each other at 22m/s. Am I right?

Comment: @RohitShekhawat No. You are stationary. When the truck is approaching, $$f_a = \frac{343}{343-22}f_0.$$After the truck passes by you and starts to recede, $$f_r = \frac{343}{343+22}f_0.$$The equation in the answer is just the ratio of these two.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misinterpreted the meaning of 'fa' and 'fr'. You are very right for sure.