# How much power and energy is (actually) in a 230 dB "click" from a whale?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, units, power

In the [BBC Science in Action](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p042smrc) podcast the acoustic power of a 1 millisecond "click" from a whale was said to be 230 dB. The related [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20160331-the-worlds-loudest-animal-might-surprise-you) mentions this number and elaborates:

> The blue whale is not the loudest animal on Earth, despite what you may have learned in school. While its calls are claimed to be louder than a jet engine at take-off, clocking in at an impressive 188 decibels (dB), the sperm whale is actually louder: its communicative clicks have been measured at 230 dB.

If I use the following equation [from here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/sound/intens.html);

$$I(dB)=10\log_{10}\frac{I}{I_0} $$

rearrange it,

$$I= I_0 \ 10^{I(dB)/10} $$

and plug in the value of 10<sup>-12</sup> watts/m<sup>2</sup> given there and use a nominal area of 1 m<sup>2</sup>, I get 10<sup>23-12</sup> =  10<sup>11</sup>  watts/m<sup>2</sup>! So, if the duration of the "click" is 1 millisecond, that's 100 MJ of energy. It's not surprising then that it can also use acoustic pulses to disable or stun potential prey.

But the article goes on to say:

> This record raises another important point about loudness. Decibels in water are not equivalent to decibels in air. "Water is denser than air, so sound travels through it differently – the speed of sound is different," says bio-acoustics expert [James Windmill](http://www.strath.ac.uk/staff/windmilljamesdr/) from the University of Strathclyde in the UK, who discovered the water boatman's remarkable call.
>
> Roughly, to convert from dB in water to dB in air, you have to subtract [around] 61 dB from the reported sound level."

I have a feeling this is somehow related to sound pressure vs intensity;  *force/area* versus *power/area*. Water is roughly 1000x as dense as air.

**Question:** I am not sure if I should be using this 61 dB offset in my calculation above. Is the energy of the "click" still 100 MJ?

Comment: You are using 230dB on the power formula, when it's really meant to be used with the amplitude formula, i.e. 20dB is a change of a factor of 10, not 10dB. That should put things into the right order of magnitude. :-)

Comment: @ChrisWhite - Ah, I assumed 1 square meter but didn't mention it - I'll fix that. Thanks!

Comment: Loudness is usually specified in $dB_{Amplitude}$, so that's twice the number of $dB_{Intensity}$.

Comment: @CuriousOne *this is* acoustic power, not loudness. 10 is correct here. However that means that the 61dB should be 30.5dB which looks like the ratio of the densities., My question is, do I need to apply that "water to air" correction to my power (and energy) estimate, or is that only for loudness considerations?

Comment: OK... so remove 61dB, then, but that still leaves you short of a factor of 1000, or so.

Comment: Water and air don't even use the same reference level.  0 dBSPL in air is 20 μPa.  0 dBSPL underwater is 1 μPa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, I went into great detail on the propagation of sound in different media in the following answer:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/266046/59023.

## **Sound**

[Intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_(physics)) (or specifically [sound intensity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_intensity)) of a linear sound wave is related to [sound pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure), $P$, through:
$$
I = \frac{ P^{2} }{ \rho_{o} \ C_{s} }
$$
where $\rho_{o}$ is the mass density and $C_{s}$ is the [speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) in the medium.  One can look up the [properties of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water) to find that $\rho_{o}$ ~ 999.972 kg/m<sup>3</sup> and $C_{s}$ ~ 1484 m/s.  We can also look up the [reference pressure level for water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwater_acoustics) (or at [NOAA](http://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/explorations/sound01/background/acoustics/acoustics.html)) finding $P_{H2O}$ ~ 1 $\mu$Pa (compared to $P_{air}$ ~ 20 $\mu$Pa) at 1 meter from source.  This corresponds to a reference intensity of $I_{o} \sim 6.74 \times 10^{-19}$ W/m<sup>2</sup> for water.

We can then use:
$$
I = I_{o} \ 10^{L/10}
$$
where $I$ is intensity (in W/m<sup>2</sup>) and $L$ is intensity (in dB).  If we use the intensity I show above and $L$ ~ 230 dB, then $I \sim 6.74 \times 10^{4}$ W/m<sup>2</sup> under water.

If we use your 1 m<sup>2</sup> area and $\Delta t$ ~ 1 ms, then the total energy would be ~67.4 J.

## **Answer**

> I am not sure if I should be using this 61 dB offset in my calculation above.  Is the energy of the "click" still 100 MJ?

No, it is much lower at ~67.4 J.  The $\sim 10^{11}$ W you found is rather extreme when you consider that it corresponds to [peak electrical power consumption of France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(power)).  Though whales are rather enormous mammals and a ~10,000 calorie diet does correspond to $\sim 10^{7}$ J of energy (i.e., diet of an Olympic athlete, which is probably much less than a sperm whale), that would still be a lot of power to produce.

Comment: So I think the answer should perhaps include "*Yes, you are right. You* do *have to subtract the 61 dB offset*"? That would drop 10${}^{11}$ watts to 10${}^{5}$ watts, and for 1 millisecond that would be 10${}^{2}$ Joules, the same as your value. Thank you for working the problem through clearly! Also I like your [linked answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/266046/83380) as well

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, I've just [used it here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31518/12102).

Comment: @uhoh - No worries.  The linked answer took a lot of work to dig up all those reference numbers and then extrapolate things properly.  Once I had that answer figured out, this one was relatively straight forward to address.

Comment: P_air is 20 μPa, not 10

Comment: @endolith - Ah good catch, thanks!