# What is the loudest possible sound?

Tags: pressure, acoustics, shock-waves

For a long time, Wikipedia has said that [the loudest possible sound is 191 dB SPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Examples_of_sound_pressure), as this [corresponds to 1 atmosphere of pressure peak-to-peak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Sound_pressure#Math_error_-_dB.28SPL.29_values_do_not_match_SPLs_in_Pa), and anything above this would be clipped at vacuum on the negative peaks, and is therefore classed as a "shockwave" rather than "sound".  (Though Wikipedia also defines a [shock wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave) as a wave moving faster than the speed of sound, regardless of amplitude.)

It gives no references, however, and I've since learned that pressure waves in air are *always* non-linear, and the science of acoustics assumes linearity and small pressure levels to simplify calculations.  So the air will already be distorted before this pressure level.

So is there a commonly-held definition of when distortion becomes too great to consider a wave "sound"?  At what dB SPL is it?  Is it possible to calculate the amplitude that a sine wave in air would be distorted by 1% THD, for instance?

Comment: You may find the following two answers helpful as well:  [http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/284104/59023](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/284104/59023) and [http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/266046/59023](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/266046/59023).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "commonly held definition" is the wikipedia one... it's not so much a question of distortion, as a question that a wave is symmetrical - that is, it should not result in a net motion of gas.  It is possible to construct a sinusoidal *pressure* wave with a peak pressure of 2 atm and a valley of 0 - from a *displacement* perspective this is a distorted wave, but from a *pressure* perspective it is not.

However, you cannot do that if the peak pressure is greater than 2 atmosphere.

Comment: What do you mean by "from a displacement perspective"?

Comment: @endolith If the sound frequency is high enough to consider the motion of the gas is adiabatic, then $PV^\gamma = \text{constant}$ where $\gamma = 1.4$ for air, so the velocity (and hence the displacement) is not a linear function of the pressure. For "normal amplitude" sound waves there is only a small change in $P$ about its mean value. Of course for a low frequency, high amplitude sound wave, the adiabatic assumption may not be strictly valid because of heat conduction in the gas.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate distortion percentage of displacement wave for a given SPL?

Comment: As the wave travels, it would become distorted "from a pressure perspective", too?  And is it 194 or 191 dB SPL?