# Sound Pressure in Partial Vacuum

Tags: pressure, acoustics, vacuum

We know that if a source of sound is put in perfect vacuum, there will be no sound. But is there a more speceific relation that is known between the sound pressure of a constant source and the vacuum of the container?

For example, suppose I have a mechanical harmonic source with amplitude A, and a microphone with minimum sensitivity of 10 db, i.e. ~ $6 * 10^{-5}$ pa of sound sound pressure. What will be the maximum vacuum at which my microphone will be able to pick up the sound?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/672/what-is-the-relation-of-sound-propagation-to-air-pressure