# When the levels of a medium that carry soundwaves are low, does that make the carried sound audibly quieter or not travel as far?

Tags: acoustics

When there isn't a medium to carry soundwaves (like air) there isn't an audible sound heard by the human ear. My question is: if air *is* present, but at the lowest level possible to carry a soundwave, would that soundwave be audibly quieter, in relation to normal atmospheric conditions *or* would the sound travel a shorter distance? My logic is that the soundwave would have to expend more energy in travel than normal atmospheric conditions, but I'm probably wrong and would like to learn why.

Comment: What do you mean by "level" in reference to air? What physical quantity?

Comment: Does this help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/672/334569

Comment: I didn't really have an exact number in mind, but thanks guys that link did answer my question thank you